# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while getting image data from CIImage captured with GPUImage

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access, gpuimage, core-image

I'm capturing video frames from my iPad's camera using the GPUImage library and trying to do some processing on the resulting image buffer.

I have the following code for retrieving a CFData byte array:

```
func testImage(image: CIImage) -> Bool {
    let ciContext = CIContext()
    let cgImg = ciContext.createCGImage(image, fromRect: image.extent)

    if let dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImg),
           imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider) {
        print("Retrieved image byte array with length: \(CFDataGetLength(imageData))")
    }

    return false
}

// Camera delegate function
func didCaptureBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
    if let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
        let image = CIImage(CVImageBuffer: imageBuffer)

        if testImage(image) {
            print("Image tested true!")
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run this code on my iPad, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS memory issue on the `if let imageData....` line.  Has anyone seen this before or know how I could debug it?

Comment: check the line above. If dataProvider is not null.

Comment: Good point @Apurv, I changed the code to do that check and I'm still running into the same error (changed question text)

Comment: Try Changing imageData type to NSData instead of CFData.

Comment: @Danoram that didn't work.  I went ahead and removed the typing of imageData with no luck either.

Comment: Darn. I'll keep looking for a solution in the meantime.

Comment: Just noticed with your code that dataProvider was declared twice. Probably need to remove the first instance in your question.

Comment: good catch, that was a typo entering my code into so

Comment: Any Updates on this issue?

Comment: Nope, still unclear what the issue is.  Going to dig in a little deeper today